# Unban a user in a specific discord server (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm working on a discord bot that mutes/unmutes/unbans users based on my servers specific requirements.

I want my discord bot to continue working exactly as it did before it crashed if/when it ever crashes.  To do this I have saved all the information I need (user ID, guild ID) to a file.

What I need help with is, how to I use that information to make it unban a user. I don't think I can use CTX, as this isn't inside a command, it's in a thread.
I already have:

```
   Bot.fetch_guild(Server)
   Bot.fetch_user(DID)
```

Please can someone help me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter where the command is run from, assuming you're using message based commands in discord.py, you'll still have access to context.

You'll have to fetch the user in a different way though...

```py
member = discord.Object(id=123)
try:
    await ctx.guild.unban(member)
except discord.NotFound:
    await ctx.send("This user was never banned/Doesn't exist")
```

Comment: Thank you!

I found out await has to be run inside async and that was causing me issues.
then I learned of @tasks.loop(seconds=30) which can handle my loop  rather than a thread